# Comparing Javascript Input

Tags: javascript

My goal is to have one password open one file and another password open a different file. The first half seems to be working but the second password will not.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var password;
var password2;
var pass1 = "password"; // place password here
var pass2 = "password2"; // place password here
password=prompt("Please enter your password:","");

if (password==pass1) {
window.location= "WEB-PL_dom.xls";

} else if (password2==pass2) {
window.location= "WEB-PL_int.xls";

} else 
window.location= "pass_failed.html"; // file to load if password is incorrect

// End -->
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare `password2` but you don't set it. You're comparing an unset variable to your `pass2` specification. I think you meant to compare it to the password prompt:

```
else if (password==pass2) {
```

As far as this script goes, `password2` is highly unnecessary.

---

While it is outside the scope of your question as it currently stands, it's worth mentioning that this script provides **NO** security for your files (and in fact creates more security risks than without its existence). You really should not rely on it to keep unauthorized parties away from your data.